Error while using ChatGoogleGenerativeAI and ChatVertexAI with langchain create_sql_agent
I am using create_sql_agent to run SQLs against a postgres database using the sample code provided in langchain documentation.
I referred to: https://python.langchain.com/docs/use_cases/sql/agents/
With ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-3.5-turbo", temperature=0), the code runs without any error.
However, when I relace the llm with ChatGoogleGenerativeAI(model="gemini-pro"), I am getting the below error:
ValueError: Unknown field for FunctionDeclaration: type
With ChatVertexAI(model="gemini-pro"), the error is:
ValueError: Unknown field for GenerationConfig: tools
I tried three different chat models as mentioned earlier

Seems ChatGoogleGenerativeAI does not support tools and hence create_sql_agent cannot use this model. Refer: https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/chat/.
